# WPF Treeview 3 levels Loop through all nodes

Tags: wpf, loops, treeview, nodes

I try to loop into each node of my 3 levels Treeview but the ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem return null value

```
foreach (DataRowView obje in tvMain.Items)
            {
                TreeViewItem TVI = (TreeViewItem)tvMain.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obje);

                foreach (DataRowView obje2 in TVI.Items)
                {
                    TreeViewItem TVI2 = (TreeViewItem)TVI.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obje2);
                }

            }
```

TVI2 is null

Here is the xaml

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvMain" Grid.Row="2">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding rsParentChild}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding production_year}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding original_title}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="program_id" Text="{Binding program_id}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possibly, item was not created yet (tree branch collapsed) or your ItemsSource binding is incorrect. But why would you loop though UI elements in WPF anyway?

Comment: Excellent, you were right. I put the code in a button to make the test after the treeview is completely charged and it's works. The code juste over is tvMain.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["treeProgram"].DefaultView; and i made the loop after. I make that for searching a value for selected the node